# Good approach to achieve Android facebook messenger type input keyboard

Tags: android, facebook-messenger, android-keypad, android-7.1-nougat

I'm developing chat app like Facebook messenger where I need to create input keyboard like Facebook messenger app provides.

Primarily I thought I should do it using tab layout with view pager. On github I found one [third party library](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/EmojiKeyboard) which provides custom keyboard with emoji.

After seeing this library I get confused that weather I should create custom keyboard or follow simple tab layout and view pager to achieve this kind of keyboard.

**What is good approach to design this kind of keyboard?**

**Edit:**

1. I found [Input Method Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) provided by Android platform which allow to create custom keyboard, but in messenger app as I seen for text they are using default keyboard and for only sticker/emoji there is replacement of default keyboard happening.
2. Android 7.1 now providing [CommitContent API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html#adding_image_support_to_imes) to use rich content using keyboards universally, still I'm not able to figure out how can I switch between default keyboard and custom keyboard?

[image] [image]

Answer (score -1):

Check out below the library:

https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

This is not 100% solution for you but can get idea about how to create keyboard like facebook messanger.

Comment: Yes, I checked that library. I've updated my question.

Comment: You want to custom keyboard for all the applications which is installed in your device right?

Comment: Nope, I want to use it only for my application. For text input type I want to use default system keyboard if user click on emoji icon then I want to popup emjoi icons which appears as emoji keyboard in replacement of default keyboard.

Comment: Have you go through the library code. As i have said earlier above library is not 100% solution but you have to modify it accourding to your requiremen.

Comment: Yes, I gone through the code. In library author have used popup view which is drawn on top of the default keyboard.Technically It's not actually a custom keyboard(IME) but it's custom view which looks like keyboard. I think there can be more better approach for this.